# Could i use content attributte in empty pseudo in css?

Tags: css, pseudo-class

```
.item:empty{
  content: "Content";
}
```

I want the field to be "Content" when it is empty. How could i do this

Comment: Do you mean `.item:empty::before`?

Comment: Thanks, i think that content works without ::before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:empty` is a pseudo-class, which allows you to style an element based on state. It is not possible to use `content` attribute with a pseudo class, or at least it does not work that way.

As @HaoWu suggested, you need to use a pseudo-element, like `:before` or `:after` to provide content to your empty `.item` element.

```css
.item:empty:before {
  content: 'Content';
}
```

```html
<div class="item"></div>
```